# Capture the result of multiple upsert statement into one output for Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert, knex.js

I am running multiple upsert statements in a single run. The queries can be add or update depending on the data. Is is possible to know if a new insert occurred.

**test_unique** is a unique constraint for column1 and column2 put together.

```
insert into test(column1,column2) values(1,1) ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT test_unique DO NOTHING;
insert into test(column1,column2) values(1,2) ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT test_unique DO NOTHING;
insert into test(column1,column2) values(1,1) ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT test_unique DO NOTHING;
```

If we take above queries

- 1st query will insert a new row
- 2nd query will also insert a new row
- 3rd query will do nothing

Any client library when running these queries as a batch will capture the output of last query and will return 0 rows.

Is there any way to know even a single insert irrespective of its position in the queries?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `returning`:

```
with i1 as (
      insert into test(column1,column2) values(1,1)
          ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT test_unique DO NOTHING
          returning *
     ),
     i2 as (
      insert into test(column1,column2) values(1,2)
          ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT test_unique DO NOTHING
          returning *
     ),
     i3 as (
      insert into test(column1,column2) values(1,1)
          ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT test_unique DO NOTHING
          returning *
    )
select id from i1 union all
select id from i2 union all
select id from i3;
```